# SSIS Script: Does not exist in the Namespace - error keeps returning - what am I missing?

Tags: c#, ssis, namespaces

I'm editing a C# script in Visual Studio for an SSIS package.

I have two lines that give me errors:

```cs
var tokenResult = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonElement>(result);
var token = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityToken(accessToken);
```

The first one complains that `JsonSerializer` does not exist in the context and `JsonElement` couldn't be found.

The second has `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` does not exist in the namespace.

If I open the package manager and run the following line, the errors go away and the script compiles cleanly.  (I've also installed through the NuGet Package Manager GUI)

```
PM> Install-Package System.IdentityModel.tokens.Jwt
```

If I save everything and run the package it fails at the script. Opening the script again reveals the errors are BACK.

Its almost like I'm not committing the changes somehow. I have tried building the package before exiting the VS editor.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nuget and SSIS don't play well together. You'll need to GAC the packages, assuming they are signed, and then repeat the process on the deployment server(s).

But you are 100% correct in your assumption. When you open a Script Task/Component, it uses a temporary folder for work. When you close the editor instance, SSIS serializes the scripts and stores them internally. Packages? Nope, they're just thrown away. Next time you open the Task/Component, you'd have to redo the install. And most importantly, when the SSIS package is executed there is no mechanism for SSIS to obtain those nuget packages.

Microsoft has had 12 years to fix this and based on the not-fixing-it-of-it, it seems clear they will not invest the engineering dollars in doing so. More's the pity.

Comment: Wonderful.  I'll give that a try.  Seems like something important that would be  a headache for people all the time.

Comment: Do you have to re-establish the reference in the code editor?  Do you point it somewhere else to access the one you've stored in the GAC?

Comment: For me, the steps were 1) download package 2) open command prompt as admin and `gacutil -if SomeAssembly.dll`  3) Remove nuget references and re-add references from GAC.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the answer because it definitely helped. Thank you!  I had to go through several iterations to get everything working.  I have another question first and you're the most knowledgeable person I've run into on the subject.   I'm going to have to post it in another comment due to length.

Comment: Now that I have my C# script and all it's references running locally, I've been having a hard time getting the references to work on the server.  I keep getting the error "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Buffers; Version=4.0.2.0...'.  I've determined it's the System.Text.Json.dll (or one of it's dependencies) that is causing the problem.  I've tried using app.config and binding redirects to point to the version of the assemblies I want the script to use, but that seems to be ignored.  Do I just need to brute force find the file problem .dll and remove it?

Comment: As you'll be using Framework on the server, have you installed the assemblies (copy from your machine to the server, open the elevated command prompt and gacutil) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/migrate-from-newtonsoft?pivots=dotnet-7-0

Comment: OMG.  That was a pain to resolve.  I did copy and use gacutil to add the assemblies.  Apparently its a common problem for that version of system.buffers to not be found.  The typical fix is to redirect to another version that DOES exist.  I never could figure out how to redirect binaries for an SSIS script.  The alternate was to abandon use of system.text.json and start using another package called newtonsoft.json.  That one didn't have the same dependencies to cause problems.

Comment: newtonsoft is the OG for all things json before MS finally got their poop in a group and added a standard library for it